# 2D Array assign value for loop

Tags: arrays, numpy

I need a bit of help. I have two arrays. Let's say

```
alpha = np.arange(1,5,1) ==> [1,2,3,4] 
beta = np.arange(5,8,1) ==> [5,6,7]
```

How do I use values alpha and beta, call a function, and assign the function return into an array whose number of rows is the same as the number of elements in beta and whose number of columns is the same as the number of elements in alpha.

```
matrix_assign = np.zeros_like((alpha, beta), dtype = 'float')

+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The function I have is a little bit more complicated so for this purpose, lets make the function do

```
np.sqrt((alpha-beta)^2)
```

This is the code I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working. Essentially, i in alpha and j in beta goes into the function, and the value that is returned shall replace the zero in its respective cell.

```
 for i in range(alpha):
        for j in range(beta):
            matrix_assign[i,j] = fn.sample_function(i,j)
```

eg when `alpha[0]` and `beta[1]` goes into the function, the output 5 is assigned to the cell `matrix_assign[1,0]`

Thank you

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np

alpha = np.arange(1,5,1) #==> [1,2,3,4] 
beta = np.arange(5,8,1) #==> [5,6,7] 

matrix_assign = np.zeros_like((alpha, beta), dtype = 'float')

for i in range(alpha):
    for j in range(beta):
        matrix_assign[i,j] = np.sqrt((alpha-beta)^2)
```

why doesn't the above code work? I'm getting the error

```
for i in range(alpha):
    TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

using `range(len(alpha))` also doesn't work. I get the error

```
matrix_assign[i,j] = np.sqrt((alpha-beta)^2) 
    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,)
```

Comment: `range` is a python function that expects an integer, not a `numpy` array.

Comment: and as for the second error you need  `matrix_assign[i, j] = np.sqrt( (alpha[i] - beta[j]) ^2 )`

Comment: Check the edit on my newer answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should be:

```
import numpy as np

alpha = np.arange(1,5,1) #==> [1,2,3,4] 
beta = np.arange(5,8,1) #==> [5,6,7] 

matrix_assign = np.zeros_like((alpha, beta), dtype = 'float')

for i in range(alpha.size):
    for j in range(beta.size):
        matrix_assign[i,j] = fn.sample_function(alpha[i], beta[j])
```

fn.sample_function needs single values of `alpha` and `beta`, not the indices.
This is very slow, though.

*If* your `fn.sample_function` is vectorized, you can do this:

```
A, B = np.meshgrid(alpha, beta)
matrix_assign = fn.sample_function(A, B)
```

You can also mash any function to be pseudo-vectorized by using `np.vectorize`.

```
A, B = np.meshgrid(alpha, beta)
matrix_assign = np.vectorize(fn.sample_function)(A, B)
```

But this is just a convenience function that doesn't have any time benefit over `for` loops.

Comment: I see. Thank you @Daniel F. Not exactly what I was expecting but it still is useful nonetheless. I found my problem to be the size of the matrix_assign array. It turns out its a 1x2 array instead of 3x4. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is a [`ufunc.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) operation.  Unfortunately, it only works with [`ufunc`s](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html).  Subtraction is a `ufunc`, but not the rest of your op.  You can do it this way:

```
matrix_assign = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(alpha, beta))
```

But in a generalized way, you'll need to make sure your `fn.sample_function` is either made up of, or tuned into (as a [custom ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html) or a [`np.frompyfunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html)), only `ufunc`.

Comment: Hello @Daniel F, thanks for the answer. Hmm, is there a way to make mine work using matrix_assign[i,j] = .... This was how I was taught to assign values to a cell in an array. What exactly am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Well, you can `np.vectorize` it.  It won't be any faster than your `for` loop though.

Comment: But unless the internals of `fn.sample_function` are already vectorized there's not an easy way, no.  I suppose you don't want to share that function.

Comment: Hmm I see. Well the function is quite long. This section of code is a small part of a bigger code that works by calling functions from different files, so there's too much to share. I'm just trying to get a better understanding of why the code above doesn't work. I know I'm on the right track but I feel like I'm missing something.